# Represent a array as key or index of second array

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

```
$arr= array(1,2,3);
$arr1= array("a","b","c");
```

i need to display the value of first array is content of second array.

like if i give input as 1, it must display "a". can any one say?

Comment: i dont barely get what you really want.

Comment: $a=(d,e,f); $b=(1=>"a",2=>"b",3=>"c"); but i need to display d=>a, e=>b, f=>c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [array_combine()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

```
$a = array('green', 'red', 'yellow');
$b = array('avocado', 'apple', 'banana');
$c = array_combine($a, $b);

print_r($c);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [green]  => avocado
    [red]    => apple
    [yellow] => banana
)
```

Comment: if the second array has key starting from like, array(1=>"a",2=>"b",...), will the array_combine work here?

Comment: Throws E_WARNING if keys and values are either empty or the number of elements does not match.

Comment: ok, if second array having key values, and i need to change that key as content of first array. what has to do?

Answer (score 2):

The function [array_combine()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) is what you want.